# Increase image size in js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pdf

I am working with a wordpress theme, that generates pdf from the post information. I want to increase the image size in the pdf output.

I assume that following is that part that prints 6 images in the pdf.

```js
// get first 6 images
            var i    = 0;
            var inc  = 0;
            var top  = top_space_int;
            var table_top_spacing = top_space_int;
            var left = left_margin;

            var left_spacing = 38;
            var top_spacing  = 0;

            $(".home-slider-thumbs ul li[data-thumb]").each( function(index, element){
                var base_64 = $(this).data("base_64");

                doc.addImage(base_64, 'PNG', left + (inc * left_spacing), (top + top_spacing), 36, 26);

                inc = (inc == 1 ? 0 : inc + 1);

                if(inc == 0){
                    top_spacing += 28;
                }

                if(index == 5){
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I want to increase the size of these images (twice or 1.5 times of the current size). 
Here is a snippet of the pdf:
[PDF SNIPPET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr57k.png)

Getting hard time to do this as I'm not handy with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing last two parameters (36, 26) it worked

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), as I see the familiar **doc.addImage()** function.  The last two parameters are width and height, respectively.

Comment: Your reply is only a partial answer...  What should the question's author do with those two parameters?

Comment: Thank you @ppovoski. At first I tried changing it, but did not work for some reason. Now it works.